# Print line in reverse order if condition is meet

Tags: text-processing, awk

Suppose we have the following file:

```
John FRIEND_OF Jose
Aspirin INTERACTS_WITH Penicilin
Tree COEXISTS_WITH Grass
Andrew FIEND_OF Jane
John INTERACTS_WITH Paula
```

I need to print the line in reverse order if the 2nd field matches `INTERACTS_WITH` or `COEXISTS_WITH`.

Here is my AWK one-liner:

```
awk '{if ($2 == "INTERACTS_WITH" || $2 == "COEXISTS_WITH") print; print $3, $2, $1; next}1' test.txt
```

The final output is:

```
Jose FRIEND_OF John
Aspirin INTERACTS_WITH Penicilin
Penicilin INTERACTS_WITH Aspirin
Tree COEXISTS_WITH Grass
Grass COEXISTS_WITH Tree
Jane FIEND_OF Andrew
John INTERACTS_WITH Paula
Paula INTERACTS_WITH John
```

However, it is tedious to specify each condition separately like in my example above (especially if you have more conditions). I wonder how to create an array of strings (e.g., `['INTERACTS_WITH', 'COEXISTS_WITH']`) and then print the line if 2nd field matches any of the elements in the array.

Comment: Why has you're output swapped John & Jose, and Andrew & Jane?

Comment: Why have you doubled up on Aspirin & Penicilin? (Once each way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample input/output is confusing at best so idk what you really want to do but here's how to specify the values you want as a string and then do something with them:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        rels = "INTERACTS_WITH COEXISTS_WITH"
        split(rels,tmp)
        for (i in tmp) {
            relSet[tmp[i]]
        }
    }
    { print }
    $2 in relSet {
        print $3, $2, $1
    }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

best I come with (can be one lined)

```
awk 'BEGIN { r["INTERACTS_WITH"]=1 ; r["COEXISTS_WITH"]=1} 
$2 in r {print $3,$2,$1 ; print ; next} 
{print}' ...
```

this is hardly a space saver.

Answer (score 1):

Done with below script

```
awk '$2 ~ /INTERACTS_WITH|COEXISTS_WITH/ {$0=$3" "$2" "$1}1' filename
```

output

```
John FRIEND_OF Jose
Penicilin INTERACTS_WITH Aspirin
Grass COEXISTS_WITH Tree
Andrew FIEND_OF Jane
Paula INTERACTS_WITH John
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using twice `print` changing the order of fields:
`{print $1, $2, $3}{print $3, $2, $1}`

```
awk '/INTERACTS_WITH|COEXISTS_WITH/ {print $1, $2, $3}{print $3, $2, $1}' file

Jose FRIEND_OF John
Aspirin INTERACTS_WITH Penicilin
Penicilin INTERACTS_WITH Aspirin
Tree COEXISTS_WITH Grass
Grass COEXISTS_WITH Tree
Jane FRIEND_OF Andrew
John INTERACTS_WITH Paula
Paula INTERACTS_WITH John
```

Or more concisely:

```
awk '/INTERACTS_WITH|COEXISTS_WITH/ {print $0}{print $3, $2, $1}' file

Jose FRIEND_OF John
Aspirin INTERACTS_WITH Penicilin
Penicilin INTERACTS_WITH Aspirin
Tree COEXISTS_WITH Grass
Grass COEXISTS_WITH Tree
Jane FRIEND_OF Andrew
John INTERACTS_WITH Paula
Paula INTERACTS_WITH John
```